# Add a column header to the dropdown part of a listbox or combo box

Tags: shieldui

I'm new to ShieldUI.

Is is possible to add a column header to the dropdown part of a listbox or combo box?

Thanks,

pt

Comment: That might not be possible... Even if you add a header item in your list, and mark it as unselectable, it would not show "sticky" on top of the item list - it will hide as the user scrolls down. You might ask Shield UI's support for that kind of functionality - their contact emails are on their website.